# calling AJAX MVC DNN

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax, dotnetnuke

What is the proper way to call an MVC method via AJAX in DNN?

I tried the following URL:

(Does not work)
/DesktopModules/MVC/MyModule/MyController/MyAction

(Works but returns full html instead of Json)
/Home/ModuleID/432/Controler/Action/

Comment: We had this issue just yesterday - And got it working by implementing the Web API framework as outlined here:
http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/142400/getting-started-with-services-framework-webapi-edition

Comment: My problem was that my template created the module as a virtual directory.  I removed the virtual directory and it worked fine.